# comparing two column in excel and pul up value from another column

Tags: excel-formula

Examples:

I have two excel files

1. file have column A
2. File have column B & C

Requirement:

If Values are same in Column A & Column B then value from Column C should be display in column D

Please let me know the formula

Answer (score 0):

In D1:

```
=IF(A1=B1,C1,"")
```

You'll need to reference the workbook and sheets if they are in different files/sheets. The easiest way is to have the files open and navigate to and click on the cell A1, B1 and C1 when typing the formula rather than typing in the cell references manually.